# How to make my module available in github (via composer.json) in magento 2

Tags: composer, magento2.1.6

I wish to make my module  available in github repository and then i wish to install it to my local using composer.json. How is this possible? Please provide me a solution, to install my module using composer.json ?

Comment: Hello @Jaisa, Mitchum solution worked ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily host your code to github
You need to have a valid composer.json on your module repo.
After you just have to add your repository into your magento composer.json like

```
"repositories": [
{ "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/mycompany/privaterepo" }
]
```

and you can make a composer require my-module

that's it.

But if you got several modules, think about packagist or Satis instance to handle it easily.

Comment: Am i need to add it in the composer.json which is in  my magento root folder

Comment: yes for sure

This is an example on what can be done :

https://gist.github.com/julienanquetil/4277cd665f8d95e877205d0119f6dc59

there is 2 composer sample, one from your module, one from magento.

Comment: it works fine, I have done as you said

Comment: If i have two repositories with different modules, But one of that, need another module, how do i add it and how to make it to be installable via composer

Comment: Please do refer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/263788/how-to-make-and-install-my-module-via-composer-with-two-private-repositories-in