# How to make and install my module via composer with two private repositories in magento 2

Tags: module, installation, magento2.3, composer, github

Problem Description:
I have created two private repositories in github under same user name.
Each repository contains different modules. But while trying to install the package via composer throws error.

**Repository 1 :
 Composer.json**

```
{
  "name": "xxx/module-abc",
  "description": "N/A",
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "VENDOR\\Abc\\": "" },
    "files": [ "registration.php" ]
  }
}
```

**Repository 2:
composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "xxx/module-psr",
    "description": "N/A",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.1.0",
    "require": {
        "xxx/module-abc": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "VENDOR\\Psr\\": "" },
        "files": [ "registration.php" ]
    } 
}
```

While tring to install to my instance , I have added below code in my 
**Magento root's composer.json
composer.json**

```
 "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        },{"type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/xxx/module-psr"}
    ],
```

Running the below command in terminal
**composer require xxx/module-psr:dev-master**

**It throws below error**

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for xxx/module-psr dev-master -> satisfiable by xxx/module-psr[dev-master].
    - xxx/module-psr dev-master requires xxx/module-abc * -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Please provide me a solution to install the module via composer

Comment: I think issue with `psr-4` tag, vendor name and module should be capital.(Potential causes:- A typo in the package name)

Comment: See i have update the name space but still it throws error

Comment: after updating name, have you update your packagist ?

Comment: I have same issue. Did you resolve this issue? If yes, could you advise me? Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can specify specific module in you module composer.json like

```
"require": { 
"php": "^7.0|^7.1", 
"magento/framework": "^101.0",
 },
```

like you do, but your module "module-abc" got some version "released"  (if you are on github self host like the "other post" and only "master branche" you should make a release on github side to be able to get it.

you can also do a composer show xxx/module-abc to see what's version is avaiblable.